# How to add or remove a string in a line depending on the presence of this string?

Tags: vimscript, vimrc

I have this two lines in my `.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <leader>d :s/$/ die();<CR>
nnoremap <leader>dd :s/ die();/<CR>
```

For debugging purposes I usually use `die();`

Maybe, someone knows, how I can toggle `die();`: Pressing `<leader>d` would add `die();` and the next time I press `<leader>d` it would remove `die();` if `die();` is present on current line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like that:

```
nnoremap <leader>d :call AddDie()<CR>

function! AddDie()
    if ( match(getline('.'), "die()") == -1 )
        execute ":s/$/ die();/"
    else
        execute ":s/ die();/"
    endif
endfunction
```

The function will test if the current line contains `die()`, if it doesnt it will add it at the end of the line otherwise it will remove it.

The mapping calls the function.

**Edit**: You can also make it a one liner, I don't like it because it is not as readable as a function but that is a good reminder of how to use a conditional structure in a mapping:

```
nnoremap <leader>d :if ( match(getline('.'), "die()") == -1 ) <bar> execute ":s/$/ die();/" <bar> else <bar> execute ":s/ die();/" <bar> endif<CR>
```

Comment: Example of expression mapping: `nnoremap <expr> <leader>d ':keeppatterns s/' . (match(getline('.'), "die();$") == -1 ? '$/ die();/' : ' die();$/') . "\<cr>"`